# How to use retrieved data from post request in JSX

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, jsx, react-query

I am retrieving data from post request which is simple object. In order to retrieve data i need to use await operator and as far as I know await can be used only in async functions. If I use async function then how to access that data outside that async function in my JSX ? or is it possible to retrieve data from post request without await ? Here is the code:

```
const handleVerifyData = async() => {
    const verifyCall = await reservationsService.verifyQueueReservations(filteredReservationIds)
    const verifiedData = verifyCall.data
    return verifiedData 
  }

<Modal
      isOpen={modals['carOnPlaceModal']?.isOpened ?? false}
      onClose={handleClose}
      styles={{
        width: "500px",
        bodyPadding: "28px 30px"
      }}
    >
        {
          verifiedData?.map(info => {
            return <Flex key={info.reservationId} style={{ flexDirection: "row", height: "40%", justifyContent: "space-evenly", alignItems: "flex-start" }}>
              <Flex style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
                <Text mb="10px">{info?.vehicleMark} {info?.vehicleModel} ({info?.vehicleBodyType})</Text>
                <CarNumberBox title={info.vehicleGovNumber} />
              </Flex>
              <Flex style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
                <Text fontSize="base" mb="10px">{T("notifications.car_on_place.form.select_box")}</Text>
                <ChakraSelect
                  value={selectedBoxes[info.reservationId]}
                  onChange={async (e: any) => {
                    const boxNumber: number = parseInt(e.target.value);
                    const res: AxiosResponse<any> =
                      await reservationsService.getCheckboxAvailability(info.reservationId, boxNumber);
                    const updatedSelectedBoxes: any = { ...selectedBoxes };

                    // If the box is taken but it  car is not being washed
                    const hasWarning: boolean = res.data?.data?.warning ?? false;
                    // If the box is taken but it the car is being washed
                    const hasError: boolean = res.data?.data?.error ?? false;
                    // const hasValidationError: boolean = Object.values(updatedSelectedBoxes).some((e: any) => e === boxNumber) ?? false;

                    updatedSelectedBoxes[info.reservationId] = boxNumber;

                    if (hasWarning) {

                      toggleModal(
                        "confirmationModal",
                        true,
                        {
                          title: `დარწმუნებული ხართ, რომ გსურთ ${boxNumber} ბოქსის შეცვლა`,
                          handleSubmit: () => {
                            setSelectedBoxes(updatedSelectedBoxes)
                            toggleModal("confirmationModal", false, { title: "" })
                          }
                        }
                      )
                      return;
                      // If denied pass () => {}
                      // If accepted
                      //const updatedSelectedBoxes: any = { ...selectedBoxes };
                      // If CheckBoxAvailability returns no warning or errors change the value 
                      // updatedSelectedBoxes[info.reservationId] = e.value;
                      // setSelectedBoxes(updatedSelectedBoxes);
                    }
                    if (hasError) {
                      toast.error(T("general.error"))
                      console.log('Warning for box');
                      return;

                    }

                    // // If CheckBoxAvailability returns no warning or errors change the value 
                    setSelectedBoxes(updatedSelectedBoxes);
                  }}
                // options={generateOptions(info?.boxCount || 0)}

                >
                  {Array(info?.boxCount).fill(0).map((option: any, index: number) => {
                    return <option key={index} value={index + 1}>#{index + 1}</option>;
                  })}
                </ChakraSelect>
              </Flex>
            </Flex>
          })
        }
</Modal>
```

verifiedData is the value i wanna access outside that function freely. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What calls `handleVerifyData`?  Presumably this function should be storing its result in *state*, not simply *returning* its result.

Comment: `handleVerifyData` is just self made function by me for only to just access async function in order to write await operator.

Comment: And presumably you plan to *call* this function somewhere, no?  And that code would in some way use the *result* of this function?  If you're planning to call this function directly in the JSX code (or in any way directly in the component's render logic) then that's the wrong approach.  Rendering is not an asynchronous operation.  Instead of trying to *wait* for the result, embrace the fact that it's asynchronous and rely on updating state to re-render the component when the data is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using this value in the rendering:

```
verifiedData?.map(info => {
```

Then presumably this value exists in *state*, no?  Something like this:

```
const [verifiedData, setVerifiedData] = useState([]);
```

In which case trying to make the rendering itself *wait* for the result is the wrong approach.  Instead, the function should update state:

```
const handleVerifyData = async() => {
  const verifyCall = await reservationsService.verifyQueueReservations(filteredReservationIds);
  const verifiedData = verifyCall.data;
  setVerifiedData(verifiedData);
}
```

When state is updated, the component will re-render with the new data.

---

As an aside, be careful with variable naming.  You are currently *shadowing* the state variable here:

```
const verifiedData = verifyCall.data;
```

Over time this could easily lead to confusion and bugs.  You can eliminate the shadowed variable entirely:

```
const handleVerifyData = async() => {
  const verifyCall = await reservationsService.verifyQueueReservations(filteredReservationIds);
  setVerifiedData(verifyCall.data);
}
```